# Dynamically generated <div> jQuery toggle behaviour issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have  dynamically generated `<div>` elements on the page and I have trouble controlling their behavior. I have an onclick Toggle function that should show/hide the div Panel. Since the `<div>`s are generated dynamically, all of them keep the same class/ID and then when I click on the element to initiate the function, the Toggle function is applied to all of the elements on the page instead of the only `<div>` that I clicked on. I understand that it is because all of them have the same ID/class but how can I fix this?

I have the following code:

```
<div class='Button'>Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div class='Panel'>some form elements...</div>
```

and the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".Button").click(function(){
    $(".Panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, make sure all your IDs are unique, they must be. Second, use the `this` keyword to refer to the element being clicked:

```
$(".Button").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".Panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

This will only slideToggle the Panel div that follows the Button div that was clicked, not all of the Panel divs.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rgv5Lgc6/)**

Answer (score 0):

You should use `next`

But I would use checkbox + label + div + css to do this (i.e. no javascript required)

Answer (score 0):

To make it more simple you can try below code, using $(this) will return current object you clicked and applying slideToggle will work for item which have been clicked. There is not any need of next().

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".panel").click(function(){
    $(this).slideToggle("slow");
  
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test1' class='panel'>test1</div>
<div id='test2' class='panel'>test2</div>
<div id='test3' class='panel'>test3</div>
<div id='test4' class='panel'>test4</div>
```